# Randomly arrange duration parts in a bigger duration

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a duration say 400 seconds. Now in this duration I have to position sub durations like 5 seconds, 90 seconds, 20 seconds, 40 seconds as randomly as possible. See image below
[image]

I am not able to come up with any logic in C# coding. One PSEUDO logic that I have in my mind is to PLACE all sub parts at the BEGINNING and then take the RIGHTMOST and distribute it to the place available from the right most part to the end and keep doing it. Problem with this approach is that in case it arranges just right of it's current location, then there will hardly be any spaces in between.

Can someone suggest something, even pseudo code will do.

Here is the code I have which works but I want it to be a bit more random

```
    long DurationOccupiedIfArrangedFromLeftWithoutAnyGap = liIntervalsAllocated.Sum();

    long startNo = DurationOccupiedIfArrangedFromLeftWithoutAnyGap;
    long endNo = TimeInSeconds - liIntervalsAllocated[liIntervalsAllocated.Count - 1];


    while (liIntervalsAllocated.Count > 0)
    {
          long positionToPlace = CommonFn.GetRandomNumberBetweenTwo((int) startNo, (int) endNo);
          Debug.WriteLine("start No is " + startNo + " End no is " + endNo + " for element selected is " + liIntervalsAllocated[liIntervalsAllocated.Count - 1] + " . ELement is placed at " + positionToPlace);
          
          startNo = startNo - liIntervalsAllocated[liIntervalsAllocated.Count - 1];
          if (liIntervalsAllocated.Count == 1)
          {
              endNo = positionToPlace;
          }
          else
          {
              endNo = positionToPlace - liIntervalsAllocated[liIntervalsAllocated.Count - 2];
          }

          liIntervalsAllocated.RemoveAt(liIntervalsAllocated.Count - 1);
    }
```

Thanks
Sujit

Comment: "as randomly as possible" means it should try to place itself in such a way that duration left in between should be uniform, it should not be like at one place there is too much void

Comment: This would be uniformly or evenly distributed and not random.

Comment: Maybe you can place one subduration at  around 100 s, the next one at around 200 s, the next one at around 300 s and the last one at around 400 s? You can randomly chose the one which is put at each place and move it randomly a few seconds away either to the left or to the right?

Comment: Just edited my question and added code that I am currently using and want to improve.

Comment: So the whole timeline is `ST + 5 + GAP + 90 + GAP + 20 + GAP + 40 + ED = 400`, then you can get this equation: `ST + ED + 3*GAP = 245 ( ST,ED,GAP >= 0 )`, Is there any difficulty to solve it?

Comment: There are different meanings about what is evenly distributed. This could either mean, that between all subdurations is an almost identically waiting time. Another approach would be the sum of a task time and one individual waiting time is for all tasks nearly the same (e.g. 5s task + 95s wait = 90s task + 10s wait). A next open point is, if you merge a task with a waiting time, should the order be waiting time, task or task, waiting time or half waiting time before and after task? Regardless of what you pick, it boils down to some simple math equations, but you have to decide.

Comment: Also beginning and end of the duration are often threated differently. Is it allowed or preferred to start or end the overall duration with a task or a waiting time?

Comment: Thanks Oliver, Shingo. I am able to tweak my above code and it is sufficient currently.

Comment: We can be of no help until "as random as possible" is replaced with a precise, unambiguous statement of the question, which is your job, not ours. btw, I've never come across the expression "pseudo logic".